# Numpy - combine two feature arrays but keep original index

Tags: python, numpy

I have two feature arrays, e.g.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
```

Now I want to combine these arrays in the following way:

```
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

The location in the array corresponds to a timestep. I tried appending and then reshaping, but then I get:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: `np.stack((a, b), axis=1)` If you want to be explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`np.dstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) to stack your lists depth-wise:

```
>>> np.dstack([a, b])

array([[[1, 4],
        [2, 5],
        [3, 6]]])
```

As noted by @BramVanroy, this does add an unwanted dimension. Two ways around that are to `squeeze` the result, or to use [`column_stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html#numpy.column_stack) instead:

```
np.dstack([a, b]).squeeze()
# or
np.column_stack([a, b])
```

Both of which return:

```
array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to sacuL's reply, you can also simply do

```py
>>> np.array(list(zip(a, b)))

array([[1, 4],
       [2, 5],
       [3, 6]])
```

In fact, this is closer to the expected result in terms of the number of dimensions (two, rather than three in sacuL's answer which you still need to `.squeeze()` to achieve the correct result).